Transaction isn't rollback when error throw(Multithreading)
The transaction isn't rollback when the RuntimeException thrown from deposit method which is calling by transfer method. The withdraw method is ran before deposit and will update the source account balance. However, it will not be rollback even deposit() is encountered error.
I am using @Service and @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) to annotate the service implementation class
Deposit Method:
protected Account depositTxn(long accId, BigDecimal amount, boolean isTransfer) throws InterruptedException {
        Account savedAcc = null;
        try {
            Account acc= addBalance(accId, amount);
            savedAcc = this.update(acc);
        } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException e){
            for(int i = 1; i <= MAX_RETRY; i++) {
                logger.info("Retring for "+ i + " time(s)");
                savedAcc = this.update(addBalance(accId, amount));
                if(null != savedAcc) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(null == savedAcc) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Hit Maximun Retry Count");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return savedAcc;
    }

Transfer Method:
    public Account transfer(long srcAccId, long toAccId, BigDecimal amount, boolean isMultithread) throws Exception {
            BankingCmoCallable callable = getBankingCmoCallable(this, "transferTxn", srcAccId, toAccId, amount, isMultithread);
            callable.prepare();
        Account savedAcc = (Account) taskExecutor.submit(callable).get();
        
        return savedAcc;
    }

protected Account transferTxn(long srcAccId, long toAccId, BigDecimal amount, boolean isMultithread) throws Exception {
        Account savedAcc = withdraw(srcAccId, amount, true, isMultithread);
                //Error thrown from this method
        deposit(toAccId, amount, true, isMultithread);
        
        addTxnH(savedAcc.getAccId(), toAccId, amount, TXN_T_T);

        return savedAcc;
    }

I have tried to put @Transactional as method level annotation but it will not working. I am using the correct import from org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

Why the use of a callable anyway here, due to the get it is blocking so it adds nothing but complexity.

try this
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
protected Account depositTxn(long accId, BigDecimal amount, boolean isTransfer) throws InterruptedException {
    // the  implementation
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
protected Account withdraw(long accId, BigDecimal amount, boolean isTransfer, boolean isMultithread) {
    // the implementation
}

Method-Level @Transactional: adding @Transactional at the method level for each transactional method (withdraw(), deposit(), transfer()) may solve the solution, especially to ensure clear demarcation of transaction boundaries. This also helps in cases where methods are invoked independently.
your import is correct import
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
When you put @Transactional it uses the default settings provided by the Spring framework that are, Propagation, Isolation, RollBack.
REQUIRED is the default propagation. Spring checks if there is an active transaction, and if nothing exists, it creates a new one. Otherwise, the business logic appends to the currently active transaction.
The default isolation level is DEFAULT. As a result, when Spring creates a new transaction, the isolation level will be the default isolation of our RDBMS.
Rollback: By default, Spring’s transaction infrastructure codes specific unchecked exceptions (runtime exceptions and errors) to automatically trigger a rollback. Checked exceptions, on the other hand, do not result in a rollback unless explicitly specified.
You can ream more about this annotation Transaction Propagation and Isolation in Spring @Transactional
